# issue with inner class of generic type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

following code fails compiling the last line even though the second last one compiles ok while the difference is only in generic type that seems to be well within its bounds.

can anyone explain? I guess it relates to erasure but why the second-last statement compiles ok?

```
public class Main {
    public static class A {
        public class Inner {
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public class Inner {
        }
    }

    public static class Wrap<T extends A> {
        public Class<T.Inner> get(Class<T.Inner> cls) {
            return cls;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Wrap<A> wa = new Wrap<>();
        Wrap<B> wb = new Wrap<>();
        // this compiles OK
        Class<A.Inner> ai = wa.get(A.Inner.class);
        // this fails
        Class<B.Inner> bi = wb.get(B.Inner.class);
    }
}
```

compiler error:

```
 /tmp$ javac -Xdiags:verbose Main.java
Main.java:24: error: method get in class Wrap<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        Class<B.Inner> bi = wb.get(B.Inner.class);
                              ^
  required: Class<Main.B.Inner>
  found: Class<Main.B.Inner>
  reason: argument mismatch; Class<Main.B.Inner> cannot be converted to Class<Main.B.Inner>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Main.A declared in class Wrap
1 error
```

Comment: Does it compile when b doesn't extend a?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: @JoshHeaps no, having the bounds as Wrap<T extends A> is the way to allow declaring generic return type that refers to T.Inner

Comment: @DavidConrad that referred topic is rather about Collections not being covariant. not applicable to my problem I suspect.

Comment: It's about generics not being covariant, it doesn't make any difference whether it's a Collection. To put it another way, the compiler has no idea that `Wrap` isn't some kind of collection (although, not one that implements `Collection`, obviously).

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, my bad referring to collections. but still not sure my problem is generics not being covariant - ie `wb` is declared as `Wrap<B>` and I am only trying to stuff it with its kind...

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think instead it has something to do with A.Inner and B.Inner not having any relationship? Or at least, not one the compiler can fathom.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain the required/found statements of java but when defining `T` as `T extends A` then `T.Inner` becomes `A.Inner`.

There are multiple possible changes to make it work:

- remove `Inner` from `B`
- define `Inner` of `B` as `extends A.Inner` and change the get method to `public <C extends T.Inner> Class<C> get(Class<C> cls)` *(works using Eclipse compiler, does not work using JDK's javac)*
- define `Inner` of `B` as `extends A.Inner` and change the get method to `public <C extends A.Inner> Class<C> get(Class<C> cls)`

How it should be changed depends on what you want to achieve using this construct of classes.

Comment: my bad in the demo code - B.Inner should extend from A.Inner as per my real case...

Comment: In the error message, the required `Main.B.Inner` is the one that `B` inherits from `A`, but the found `Main.B.Inner` is the one that `B` declares itself. They just happen to have the same name.

Comment: _when defining T as T extends A then T.Inner becomes A.Inner_ - right, I noticed that when dealing with this problem

Comment: @MarkusBenko: your second option still fails compiling the second statement:

`required: Class<I>
  found: Class<B.Inner>
  reason: inference variable I has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: B.Inner
    upper bounds: B.Inner
  where I,T are type-variables:
    I extends B.Inner declared in method <I>get(Class<I>)
    T extends A declared in class Wrap`

Comment: This unfortunately wouldn't be the first time that Eclipse's compiler behaves differently than Java's own. I will check later.